# Nested AND and OR for a filter option using radio button

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I made a filter option using the radio button. The radio button values are stored in a PHP session. For the "state" radio buttons, its value is stored in the $state=$_SESSION["state"]; while the "condition radio buttons are stored in the $condition=$_SESSION["condition"];. Below is the list of the value for the buttons:

State:
-allstate
-new
-old
-Unknown state

Condition:
-allcondition
-Available/Unassigned
-assigned
-repair
-missingpart
-missingeq
-refurbished
-Unknown condition

```
<?php
if($state=='allstate' AND ($condition=='Available/Unassigned' OR $condition=='assigned' OR 
$condition=='repair' OR $condition=='missingpart' OR $condition=='mmissingeq' OR 
$condition=='defective' OR $condition=='refurbished' OR $condition=='Unknown condition')){
$sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no WHERE 
eq_condition='$condition' AND (eq_state='new' OR eq_state='old' OR eq_state='Unknown state')  ORDER 
BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}

if($state=='allstate' AND $condition=='allcondition'){
$sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no WHERE   
eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' OR eq_condition='assigned' OR eq_condition='repair' OR 
eq_condition='missingpart' OR eq_condition='missingeq' OR eq_condition='refurbished' OR 
eq_condition='Unknown condition') AND (eq_state='new' OR eq_state='old' OR eq_state='Unknown State')  
ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}

if($condition=='allcondition' AND ($state=='new' OR $state=='old' OR $state=='Unknown state')){
$sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no WHERE 
eq_state='$state' AND (eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' OR eq_condition='assigned' OR 
eq_condition='repair' OR eq_condition='missingpart' OR eq_condition='missingeq' OR 
eq_condition='refurbished' OR eq_condition='Unknown condition') ORDER BY empl_firstname, 
 empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}

else{
    $sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no WHERE 
eq_state='$state' AND eq_condition='$condition' ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  
ASC");
 }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
   <td>-td content-</td>
   </tbody>
   <?php
     }
      ?>
```

I made four scenarios but only the 
if($condition=='allcondition' AND ($state=='new' OR $state=='old' OR $state=='Unknown state'))

and

else{ $sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no WHERE eq_state='$state' AND eq_condition='$condition' ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
  }

are working.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the solution was so simple. I just changed some of if() statement to elseif() statement. It should follow the format in creating the if(), elseif() and else{} statement.

```
<?php
if($state=='allstate' && $condition=='allcondition'){
$sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no 
WHERE eq_state='new' OR eq_state='old' OR eq_state='Unknown state' 
AND(eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' OR eq_condition='assigned' OR 
eq_condition='repair' OR eq_condition='missingpart' OR eq_condition='missingeq' OR 
eq_condition='refurbished' OR eq_condition='Unknown condition')
ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}
elseif($state=='allstate' AND ($condition=='Available/Unassigned' OR 
$condition=='assigned' OR   $condition=='repair' OR $condition=='missingpart' OR 
$condition=='mmissingeq' OR $condition=='defective' OR $condition=='refurbished' OR 
$condition=='Unknown condition')){
$sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no 
WHERE eq_condition='$condition' AND (eq_state='new' OR eq_state='old' OR 
eq_state='Unknown state')  ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}
elseif($condition=='allcondition' AND ($state=='new' OR $state=='old' OR 
$state=='Unknown state')){
$sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no 
WHERE eq_state='$state' AND (eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' OR 
eq_condition='assigned' OR eq_condition='repair' OR eq_condition='missingpart' OR 
eq_condition='missingeq' OR eq_condition='refurbished' OR eq_condition='Unknown 
condition') ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}

else{
    $sql = ("SELECT * from eq_inv left JOIN empl_tbl on 
 eq_inv.empl_no=empl_tbl.empl_no WHERE eq_state='$state' AND eq_condition='$condition' 
ORDER BY empl_firstname, empl_lastname, middlename  ASC");
}
```